# Why are the pictures not viewable?

Tags: patent-drawings

In reference to the patent: [US20170027219](https://www.google.com/patents/US20170027219)

Hi,

I would very much like to see the photos of the actual design of this patent, but cannot find a way to view them despite the method I try.

Is it possible to have them re-uploaded or emailed?

Thank you!

Comment: You might note that the referenced document is a pending application and is not an issued patent, whereas https://patents.google.com/patent/US9474304B2/en would refer to an issued patent (with somewhat different claims) as granted on 10-25-2016.

Answer (score 1):

Google/patents has some issues, patents.google however normally works fine:

https://patents.google.com/patent/US20170027219A1/en

Answer (score 0):

If Google Patents doesn't work (it won't work for very recently issued patents), try https://www.pat2pdf.org/

If that doesn't work for you and you know how to code in PERL, the article at http://www.fresnoip.com/2018/03/patent-tuesdays-and-application.html contains PERL code at the bottom that retrieves the image of the patent, including the drawings, for you.